# Internal: Failed to call ThenRnnForward with model config: [rnn_mode, rnn_input_mode, rnn_direction_mode]

Tags: python, keras

My Neural Network based on CuDDNLSTM layers gives an error that I do not understand properly. The error pops up randomly after training for about 30 minutes. The full error is:

```
InternalError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Internal: Failed to call ThenRnnForward with model config: [rnn_mode, rnn_input_mode, rnn_direction_mode]: 2, 0, 0 , [num_layers, input_size, num_units, dir_count, max_seq_length, batch_size]: [1, 32, 32, 1, 700, 32] 
     [[{{node cu_dnnlstm_4/CudnnRNN}}]]
     [[loss_2/mul/_145]]
  (1) Internal: Failed to call ThenRnnForward with model config: [rnn_mode, rnn_input_mode, rnn_direction_mode]: 2, 0, 0 , [num_layers, input_size, num_units, dir_count, max_seq_length, batch_size]: [1, 32, 32, 1, 700, 32] 
     [[{{node cu_dnnlstm_4/CudnnRNN}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

The summary of the model looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(32, input_shape=(lengtharray,1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(32))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
model.summary()
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, validation_split = 0.1, shuffle=True, batch_size = 32, callbacks=callbacks_list)

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
cu_dnnlstm_3 (CuDNNLSTM)     (None, 700, 32)           4480      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 700, 32)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
cu_dnnlstm_4 (CuDNNLSTM)     (None, 32)                8448      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 33        
=================================================================
Total params: 12,961
Trainable params: 12,961
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I know that this is a probably a memory limit issue. However, the model gave no error while training with exactly the same parameters with 400 epochs, when I used 10% of the data. I originally used ~7000 samples, the error occurs when I use ~ 75.000 samples.

The input vectors are the same length and the batchsizes etc are the same. What is the reason that the model crashes when using more samples and not with a small sample size? I'm running a RTX2070super.